# Android App and Compatibility

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

What parts of the Android project makes devices incompatible?

My first project was released, and it's pretty simple. It only works on 6880 devices according do Google Play.

My girlfriend's phone is incompatible, although she always used this app when I installed direct through the .apk file.

The manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="my.project" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <application android:label="AppName" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <activity android:name="my.project.AppName" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|mnc|mcc|locale|fontScale|uiMode" android:label="Credito">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
  <!-- Android 2.3.3 -->
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
  <!-- OpenGL ES 2.0 -->
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <!-- USB support -->
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
  <!-- Disable screen compatibility modes -->
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: "What parts of the Android project makes devices incompatible?" -- manifest entries mostly. "It only works on 6880 devices" -- to paraphrase Bill Gates, 6880 devices ought to be enough for anyone. :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare could you show an example?

Comment: Um, [`<uses-feature>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) is a common culprit. Pay particular attention to [the permissions that imply feature requests](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions). Another problem spot is [`<compatible-screens>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html).

Comment: Could this <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
be a problem?

Comment: No, that's fine. If you had `false` for the smaller sizes, that would serve as a filter for screens with those sizes. `true` will not filter anything.

Comment: I updated the question with my manifest. Thanks.

Comment: No, that's fine. Also note that the manifest that you wrote is merged with manifests from libraries. Examine the manifest merger report at `build/outputs/logs/` of your module and the merged manifest in `build/intermediates/manifests/` of your module.

Comment: Might be the `usb.host` feature. What does your app need it for? It's not supported on all devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Device compatibility described on [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html). In general it includes 3 sections:
* Device features;
* Platform version
* Screen configuration;

According to your manifest there are next possible problems:

1. "android.hardware.usb.host" - app need a device that guaranteed to support the USB host APIs. According to the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html):

Because not all Android-powered devices are guaranteed to support the USB host APIs, include a "uses-feature" element that declares that your application uses the android.hardware.usb.host feature.

this basically means that the app might even work on the phone (by direct install for example) till the moment when such API are called.

2. android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="14"

Does your girlfriend's phone have something earlier than Android 2.3.3 (like 2.2)? And again, this does not means that it won't work, it just means that it might fail on her phone if there is a call to any method that is not exists prior to the Android 2.3.

3. uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"

This should not be a problem since:

OpenGL ES 2.0 - This API specification is supported by Android 2.2 (API level 8) and higher.

4. screen resolutions also should not be a problem since you have switched on all 4 possible major resolutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Problem 1 was the biggest. :)

Comment: Most of the phones are included... but still, her LG L65 (Android 4.4.2) won't! Do you have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JudismarJunior It's pretty easy to empirically test if a device supports the USB host functionality: Plug in a USB mouse, and see if you can use it to control the user interface.

Comment: @RetoKoradi thanks for the heads up. I actually misunderstood that feature, but that's pretty good to know!